# Windows 10 UWP Single sign-on

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, azure-mobile-services

How can I add the single sign-on UX shown here? This is from Wunderlist. I see a similar UI shown when signing in on some other apps on Windows 10, but can't find an example of how it can be done. It just uses the existing Microsoft Account if already signed in.

I'm currently working on examples based off Azure Mobile Apps, but it's not quite the same.

[image: Wunderlist]

Comment: This seems to be a step in the right direction: http://jshapland.com/single-sign-on-with-azure-mobile-services-in-a-uwp-app/ It recognizes that I'm signed in with my MS account, but it's still not quite the same UX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI you've see is create by [**AccountsSettingsPane** class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.applicationsettings.accountssettingspane.aspx). This class provides methods to show the accounts pane and also to enable the app to register callbacks when the accounts flyout is about to be displayed.

To learn how it can be done, you can check the official [**Web account management sample**](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebAccountManagement) in GitHub.

To use the existing Microsoft Account that is already signed in, please refer to Single Microsoft Account scenario in this sample.

Comment: Any guidance on how this can be used together with Azure Mobile App? @Jay Zuo - MSFT

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure Mobile App, I'd suggest you ask a new question about your problem.